# Testing in vscode give sunrsasign.jar not found

Tags: java, java-8, visual-studio-code

For jdk1.8_201 when i run testng tests, I get

```
    "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar" .
```

Why is vscode searching for it in .../jre/lib. when it is located in rt.jar.

Comment: Could you please check your Java Dependency ==》JRE System Library to see if this library is one of your project dependency. By the way, are you using Junit? Detailed reproduce steps will help a lot.

Comment: Yes, this is my project dependency. But It works fine on eclipse. Why VSCode is having problem? Same problem occures for generated demo project.